# Is there any way to create background services which will run even if the app is closed?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating a Xamarin application where I used to store documents, I need to create a background service that should run continuously even if the app is closed.(for both android and iOS)

I am trying to create this background service for deleting the documents from my mobile app every 5 days.

So, adding a never-ending process for deleting documents based on days from the mobile app is a good way to do it? I need an idea of how to implement it.

I did some research I can only see MessageCenter for doing background process, but i need a way to implement a never ending background services. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for a job that is executed periodically.

The link below provides an introduction to android jobs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler

Comment: I followed the documentation it helps, I wanted to run my job for each 5 days. How can i schedule that with the jobinfo object? Can you please help me with that?